# Subtract a time input from another time input android studio java

Tags: java, time

Developing app in Android Studio. Java

I am having trouble subtracting a time from another time.
I want to have a bedtime and waketime.
Then somehow get the hours that I would have slept.
I was thinking 12:00 - bedtime + waketime but am a bit confused.
Any ideas?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText bedtimeEnter;
private EditText waketimeEnter;
private TextView sleepNumber;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    bedtimeEnter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bedtime_enter);
    waketimeEnter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.waketime_enter);
    sleepNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sleep_number);
}


public void buttonClick(View view) {
    String bedtime = String.valueOf(bedtimeEnter.getText());
    String waketime = String.valueOf(waketimeEnter.getText());

    String sleep = "12.00" - bedtime + waketime;
}
}
```

Really confused.
Lot of help needed. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to parse your Strings that denote your bedtime and waketime into Some Date Object which java version are you using? if anything before Java 8 then look at package [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). If you are using java 8 then look at [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class. Parse your values into [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) And then [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) and you will get your sleep time